# .htaccess RewriteRule not working, <name>.php is loaded instead of index.php?page=<name>

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have a website with the following file structure:

```
/www
    /nl
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    /fr
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    /de
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

The `index.php` file in the `www` folder is a language selection page, that links to the `index.php` files in the `nl`, `fr` and `de` folders. The latter index.php pages build the webpage and load the page content from `<page>.php`.

In the past, the pages were loaded like this:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/index.php?page=contact
```

This would load the content of `/nl/contact.php` into the sites structure.

To make the website more SEO friendly, we changed this to:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact
```

This can go up to 3 levels deep (`/nl/nav-level1/nav-level2/nav-level3`)

The index.php files inside the `nl`, `fr` and `de` folders, have an algorithm that 301 redirects the old page url to the new page url for people who visit the site from the old urls.

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
header('location:' . $newurl);
exit;
```

The .htaccess file in the root www directory looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteBase wijzigen in / (online)
RewriteBase /

# PDF: redirect pdf file in wrong directory to root language directory (nl/fr/en)
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr|de)(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)+/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.pdf)/?$ $1/$3 [NC,L,R=301]

# pages: redirect index.php in wrong directory to the correct language directory (nl/fr/en)
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr|de)(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)+/(index.php)/?$ $1/$3 [NC,L]

# pages: convert SEO friendly url to index.php?page=<page>
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr|de)(/[a-zA-Z0-9\-/]+)*/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
```

**This worked fine, untill I moved this website to the servers of our new hosting provider.**

Now, when i go to `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact`, instead of loading `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/index.php?page=contact`, `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact.php` is loaded directly. This means I get to see the content of the page, but without the other structure and layout of our website.

I checked whether the `.htaccess` file works, by

- **putting my .htaccess contents in the .htaccess tester on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and testing the urls of my website**: this returned the expected urls
- **putting something invalid in the .htaccess file**: this returns a server error, as expected
- **redirecting everything to a test page**: this redirects all urls to the test file.

I then discovered that I could work around the problem by creating folders inside the language folders (`nl`, `fr`, `de`) with the same names as the php files. This made the seo friendly urls load the page as expected, but somehow, the get variables are still added to the seo friendly urls.

```
/www
    /nl
        /contact
        /...
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    /fr
        /contact
        /...
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    /de
        /contact
        /...
        index.php
        contact.php
        ...
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

Instead of `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact` I always get redirected to `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact/?page=contact`

If I go to `http://www.ourdomain.com/nl/contact/` The get variables are not added to the url.

I've been working and searching for hours on this problem and I don't get my head around it. Any valuable input would be appreciated.

Comment: have you set `AllowOverride FileInfo Options`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem.

Apparently, `MultiViews` was set on the new server. Therefore, filenames without extension were matched to files with extensions, causing `http://example.com/nl/contact` to load `http://example.com/nl/contact.php`.